# Company email invitations going to spam - Gmail

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Some of the email invitations using our company's custom email are being marked as spam in Gmail.
This is only happening for a couple of users, and seems to only be for invitations. I've set up SPF, DKIM records etc. and still having the same issue, even with the emails being marked as 'not spam'.
The email accounts were set up in Google Cloud Platform.
Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Or where it may be coming from?

Comment: Use an online service that analyzes your email and tells you what to improve. There are many reasons that an email can be flagged as SPAM or Junk. Next, I would use commercial email services and not Gmail to send emails. Note: Google Cloud Platform does not provide email services. Double-check what you are actually using.

Comment: What is actually sending the invites? A service designed for email, or instances/scripts you have running in the cloud? If it’s the latter, you’re probably destined to always have issues. If it’s the former, you may want to check with that service to see how to troubleshoot further.